# How to stop an NSTimer that I don't know is released or not

Tags: iphone, xcode, crash, nstimer

Sorry to ask this question, but it's now day 3 I try to solve this problem and have no progress so far.

The problem is this: during a game there is a pause between the user answered a question and the next question. Also in several other cases there are such pauses in gameplay. For this I use one NSTimer.

In .h I have:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSTimer *scheduleTimer;
```

and in the .m

```
@synthesize scheduleTimer;

scheduleTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target: self selector: @selector(playFeedbackSound) userInfo: nil repeats: NO];
```

now this works just fine. But when the user exits the ViewController I need to invalidate the timer. Otherwise the timer will fire and then crash the app or pops up stuff that does not belong in the other view etc.

Therefore I write:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [scheduleTimer invalidate];   
}
```

now this does the job if the timer is actually set. But if there is no such timer scheduled, the app just crashes.

I tried probably everything there is, including @try (which crashes the app too, Zombie says "*** -[CFRunLoopTimer invalidate]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x567640"). Since the timer gets released after it is done, a [scheduleTimer isValid] will just crash the app as well.

Now I'm already pretty desperate, and as a last resort I'm thinking of replacing the timer with UIView animateWithDuration that does nothing visible.

However, I think this should be a pretty standard situation. I just don't know why I can't find an answer to this very obvious task. Can you help? Thank you

Comment: It may be worth noting that you're not using the dot-notation while setting your property. Even though it may not have happened before this means your timer could be destroyed before it actually fires or gets invalidated, especially under low-memory conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the `NSTimer` gets autoreleased before you `invalidate` it.

So you should do:

```
scheduleTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target: self selector: @selector(playFeedbackSound) userInfo: nil repeats: NO] retain];
```

And you should also `release` the timer in `viewWillDisappear:`

```
[scheduleTimer release];
```

But an even better solution is probably to use the dot property syntax to care of retain/release:

```
self.scheduleTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target: self selector: @selector(playFeedbackSound) userInfo: nil repeats: NO];
```

And then:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    if (self.scheduleTimer != nil) {
        [self.scheduleTimer invalidate];
        self.scheduleTimer = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: *** -[CFRunLoopTimer invalidate]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5365ce0

Comment: It seems to pass the test and then run into the invalidate. So it's not nil, but then ... what is it?

Comment: Then i think the real problem is that you don't use `self.scheduleTimer =` when assigning the timer as is will return a autoreleased NSTimer

Comment: `self.scheduleTimer =` will retain the timer so that it will not be autoreleased

Comment: Uuuhhhhhh Mattias, that totally retained it! :-) Thank you! And could you please point me to a document explaining me more about the use of self. ?

Comment: You can read about it here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17

Answer (score 0):

Create a method to invalidate the timer that also sets the property to nil:

```
- (void) invalidateTimer
{
    if (self.scheduleTimer) {
       [self.scheduleTimer invalidate];   
       self.scheduleTimer = nil;  
    }
}
```

... and then call that method whenever you invalidate the timer. For example:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{
   [super viewWillDisappear: animated];
   [self invalidateTimer];
}
```

Make sure your timer is retained by using:

`self.scheduleTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target: self selector: @selector(playFeedbackSound) userInfo: nil repeats: NO];`

Comment: Unfortunately NSTimer gets released automatically, and I don't see how the ViewController can be delegate of NSTimer, so that I could set it to nil

Comment: However, thank you for the code example, I also forgot to put [super viewWillDisappear: animated]; :-o

Comment: Super call should go after the invalidate call.  Teardown super calls always come at the end, setup super calls always at the start.